# Android firebase throws authentication error while trying to access storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

EDIT: I just restarted Android Studio after cleaning the project and invalidating cache. Now I get this error -

```
E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": 
"Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
```

I'm getting the following error that prints infinitely.

> 2020-09-27 17:00:32.931 11755-11863/com.example.XXXXXX E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.

In my app I've created the user properly, and `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();` does NOT return null. But if it does, I handle it by logging them in successfully or creating another user. My app now has 160+ users created, in less than half a day. I don't think I've even run the app that many times for testing. 'Sign in with email', and 'anonymous sign in' options are enabled in auth settings.

The problem starts when I try to access the storage. I get the above mentioned auth token error. The folder and file exist and this is how I'm trying to download the files -

```
            fstore.child("gs://XXXXXX-XXXX.appspot.com/Books/XXXX").listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                for(StorageReference sref : listResult.getItems())
                {
                    tempFilename = sref.getName();
                    File tmpFile = new File(tempSubDir, tempFilename);
                    try {
                        tmpFile.createNewFile();
                        sref.getFile(tmpFile).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(tabtwoactivity.this, "File download failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                System.out.println("ERROR: "+ e.toString());
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //System.out.println("IIIIII: "+sref.getName());
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(tabtwoactivity.this, "Fetching Directory XXXXX Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

I've tried using `fstore.child("XXXX").listAll()` but that gave me an avalanche of different errors, mainly focused around `Folder not found`. My storage has the folder and files. I've even played around with the storage rules - `allow read, write;`,  `allow read, write: if request.auth!=null`,  `allow read, write: if request.auth==null`. But nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you signed in android studio with your google account?

Comment: @Jandroid Yup, I have. But is that really a big enough factor to consider?

Comment: Because when I didn't sign in android studio, I got errors.

Comment: But it's not something big to think about.

Comment: It looks like android studio has not been able to access your database.

Comment: Check this: https://www.google.com/search?q=error+code+403+means&oq=error+code+403+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.7026j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: This is causing the error: allow read, write: if request.auth!=null

Comment: Check this also: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/get-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this in your google.json:

```
service firebase.storage {
  // The {bucket} wildcard indicates we match files in all storage buckets
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Match filename
    match /filename {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```